# How to validate OAuth2 State in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I looked at the [GitHub OAuth API](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps/) and saw that one requirement to send to the endpoint is `state`.

Sending it is trivial - but how do you validate that the `state` you sent is the same one you’re receiving?

I thought of using [browser caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/cache/) but it seems like it’s for views of Django and improving performance.

I thought of [sending a CSRF token](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/) as the `state` but it seems it’s meant for forms you generate.

In short, how do you validate `state` in Django? Is there a Pythonic way in Django to do so?

Comment: When you create it, you can store it in the user's [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/). When you receive the response, just check `state` against the value you stored in the session. Note that there are existing Django packages that have been written so you don't have to go through all the complexities yourself. It's not that easy to write a completely secure OAuth2 client (django-allauth, python-social-auth, django-oauth-toolkit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user's [*session*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/) is the best place to store variables that are session related, which is the case here.

So generate your `state` and store it into the user's session:

```
request.session['github_state'] = state
return render(<template with github link>, context={'state': state})
```

Then when you receive the user's authorised GET request:

```
if request.session.get('github_state') and not request.GET.get('state') == request.session['github_state']:
    # abort here
else:
    code = request.GET.get('code')
    # POST request with code to GitHub to fetch the access token
```

I'm checking that the session variable isn't empty/None, otherwise both might be empty and the check would pass.